# Redirection on AJAX success using window.location.replace()

Tags: javascript, ajax, coffeescript

I am trying to redirect the page on the successful ajax call, the following code works fine,

```
$.ajax(
      {
      type: "POST",
      url: path,
      data: response1,
      contentType: "application/json",
      success: ->

                 window.location.replace("http://172.16.17.141:81/configuration/manage_users")

      });
```

Problem with this approach is that the path I am giving is fixed, I want something like,

```
$.ajax(
      {
      type: "POST",
      url: path,
      data: response1,
      contentType: "application/json",
      success: ->
                 alert(window.location.host + "/configuration/manage_users")#Gives right path

                 window.location.replace(window.location.host + "/configuration/manage_users")   
                 #Does not work, I even tried window.location.host.toString()
      });
```

The page does not redirect with the above approach and instead of the URL, the page redirects to "about:blank".

Any help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem was that I was not specifying the protocol,

```
window.location.replace(window.location.protocol + "//" +
                                  window.location.host + "/configuration/manage_users")
```

worked fine, I found out that,

```
window.location = window.location.protocol + "//" +
                                         window.location.host + "/configuration/manage_users"
```

is better for redirection.

Answer (score 0):

Normally you could do this from server. You have to respond correct HTTP headers. What is your back end technology? In node.js it will look like this:

```
var host = 'http://172.16.17.141:81'
response.writeHead(302, {
  'Location': host + '/configuration/manage_users'
});
response.end();
```

Answer (score 0):

Would this work?

```
$.ajax
  type: 'POST'
  url: path
  data: response1
  contentType: 'application/json'
  success: ->
    window.location = "//#{window.location.host}/configuration/manage_users"
```