# location.replace not replacing current url in history

Tags: javascript

I have the following code that is executed on a button click:

```
location.replace(window.location.href.split('?')[0] + _new_urli);
```

My url looks like: https://mywebsite.com/website/?page=page1

For the sake of example we have:

**Current behavior:**
After location.replace() the current url stays in history and user can click back to it

**Desired/intended behavior:**
If successful the user will be forwarded. If they press back will not be able to visit the page i used location.replace on.

This is the described functionality on: http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_loc_replace.asp

Comment: Just to clarify you want the user to go 2 time back when he click back button ?

Comment: I want page2 to be replaced with page3 so the user cannot return to page 2 after the data has been posted.

Comment: I dont see any miss conception are you sure `_new_urli` is a string ?

Comment: Yes, it works as if I'm using location.assign ()

Comment: Well really strange... You have no error in your console? This is the last thing I could see. Personally it is completely working.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could probably use the `history`of navigation.

Something like `history.go(-2);` should work.

If you want to modify url you can have a look at [`history.pushState(null, null, "newURL");`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/History_API) or in your case probably more `history.replaceState()`.

The thing is the back button does not keep change so if your `data` is changed on page 3 you need an other way to pass it to the browser which could be the `state object` (the first parameter null) that can be set as `{object: value,...}`

[This while probably interest you too](https://css-tricks.com/using-the-html5-history-api/). The thing is without knowing the behaviour of your site its difficult to help you find a proper solution. I hope this will inspire you.

Comment: Ill take a look at the links, I was under the impression that location.replace replaces the current page in history with a new one. That's all I really want to do

Comment: Thank you for the reply but this doesn't seem to fix what I'm trying to do. Why wouldn't my location.replace not replace the current url as intended?: http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_loc_replace.asp

Comment: I think this is due to your data no ? Can you console.log() it ?

Comment: Have you tried the solution of this post ? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25607582/redirection-on-ajax-success-using-window-location-replace

Comment: console.log what? The data string? It is returning normally. Everything is working properly except the fact that the current url isn't being replaced. Its just forwarding to the next page when it should be replaced.

Comment: See comment just before. And well if you don't have alert it should indeed work. So this must be due to specificity of Ajax

Comment: I think there has been a miscommunication, Im going to edit the original question. Ill try outside of a ajax request

Comment: Still no luck, Im going to edit the question to try to simplify things